# How to change one object into another object?

Tags: actionscript-3

This is mostly a question about code design. What you see here is a very condensed version of the original code.

An example of the code is:

```
player.rest();
```

This makes the player sleep.

I have other methods such as walk, run, talk etc. which all work great. The one that is a problem is polymorph. It changes the player from a human object to another object. The solution I came up with is this:

```
class main
  {
      var human:Human = new Human;
      var alien:Alien = new Alien;
      var cow:Cow = new Cow;
      var player = human;

      enterframe loop{
       //other code 
       if (player does something)
       player.polymorph = "alien";

       switch (player.polymorph)
       {
         case "alien":
         player = alien;
         break;
         case "cow":
         player = cow;
         break;
         //etc
       }
       player.update();
     }
  }
```

I want something that looks like this:

```
  class main 
    {
      var human:Human = new Human;
      var alien:Alien = new Alien;
      var player = human;

      enterframe loop
      {
       player.polymorph(alien);
      }
    }
```

I know my original solution is the wrong way to go about things as it encourages spaghetti code. How could I do it differently? I don't mind a whole rewrite, but need an example to help push me in the right direction. I hope this makes sense and thanks for the help.

If the second one can work, what would the polymorph function look like?

I thought of making a class called player and changing what that extends, but to my knowledge that can't be done? Plus I would like to change the character to something already in game rather than a new object.

Comment: And why don't you just do *player = alien;* then?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense for this example, but sadly not what I'm after. Trying to think about how to reword it, also looking into the other answer.

Comment: Do the human and alien objects have distinct statistics, or are they shared? For example, if your human has 50 hp and you morph into an alien, does it have 50 hp or whatever your hp was last time you were an alien

Comment: They are not shared. The idea is you're switching from an in game human to a alien. You would have only the alien's health and inventory. The actual code contains also: onEnterFrame {control(player)}. Which decides who you control, when player = human you control the human, when player = alien you control the alien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be using a single class, in this case, your Player class, and a [finite state machine](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html). You'd have a Player class, which can be set to different states, such as HUMAN, ALIEN, COW, etc. When a polymorph event occurs you update the Player's state, perhaps by calling an initState() method, and handle the logic for being a human, alien, cow, accordingly in whatever method updates your player.

Assuming the player has an update() method it could contain the following:

```
switch (state) {
    case ALIEN: 
       // do alien stuff
    case COW:
       // do cow stuff
    case HUMAN:
       // do human stuff
}
```

Next, instead of handling the various polymorph states in a switch statement, your Player class could have a polyMorph method that takes a state as a parameter:

```
public function polymorph(newState:Int) {
    state = newState;
    initState(state); // You could even just call the initState method instead, and completely omit the polymorph method
}
```

Using a finite state machine here would eliminate the need for numerous objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this especially the article. Very useful. I think this solution has potential to work, I just have to wrap my head around how I would use it in my code. The one thing holding me back from saying this answers the question is: I have also written in my code onEnterFrame(){control(player)} I want it so when it equals alien you actually control the alien that is presented on the screen, rather than a pre-made alien. This way if the alien was attacked by something on the screen you now have the health of that alien.

Comment: Personally, I'd make sure all of the onscreen sprites extend the same class (eg. Actor, or something that makes sense to you) and use a boolean named 'playerControlled' to achieve what you want.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! This idea solved my problem, made the code not messy and everything. Really appreciate it. Thanks.